# Bind Images With System Folder Path in XAML/C#

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am developing an application in XAML/C#, where path of the image in stored in the list. The path contains spaces because it is the path of the file with in the computer C Drive. I am unable to bind it. I tried using

```
<Image Name="ImageOffer">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
```

Can anyone tell me the way of binding images from outside folder of application in XAML.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind image from ANY location. WinRT has sandboxed environment, so you can bind image from known locations only like libraries, local folder, asset folder.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public ImageSource ImgSource
    {
         get
         {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + this.ImagePath));
         }
    }
}

<Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}" />
```

Please note to access files stored inside the application package use the ms-appx: scheme &
to access files stored in the application state, use the ms-appdata: scheme. Application state may be stored in a local folder, a roaming folder, or a temp folder.

Some more resources.

[How to load file resources (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322.aspx)

[Handling binding between WinRT Image control and ViewModel for local file system images](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/11/21/image-file-binding/)

Comment: But my requirement is to bind image in that way :(